# ARIMA R vs Minitab

Tags: r, time-series, arima, minitab, acf-pacf

A simple question: Is the algorithm for calculating the fits using the `Arima` function of the `forecast` package of R different from that of Minitab.

I tried to fit an ARIMA (0,1,0)(0,1,1)[12] model in R using:

```
fit1 <- Arima(data.ts, order=c(0,1,0), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=12))
```

I tried to recreate the same in Minitab.

I haven't included constant for either of my models.

This is the resulting ACF plot for residuals from R:

```
Acf(fit1$residuals)
```

[image]

The following is the resulting ACF plot for the same data and model from Minitab:

[image]

As you can see, the two graphs differ significantly.

So, I wanted to ask if there is a difference in the algorithm of calculating fitted values for both?

If yes, then which platform should be preferred: R or Minitab? And why?

Comment: The values of ACF do not seem to differ much, but the confidence interval does differ.

Comment: Yes, the difference in the confidence interval is quite apparent. I checked the actual values of residuals for both minitab and R and there exists a difference in them too, although it is minor.

Comment: I would be more interested in the parameter estimates from both R and Minitab. Can you include those?

Comment: The plots appear *identical* to me, except that the Minitab plot has very low resolution because it did not adapt its vertical scale to the range of the values.  The confidence bands have nothing to do with the fitted values and therefore are not relevant.  That leaves us with no useful information to go on.